# When using PyMongo, No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo, apscheduler

The code works fine printing to screen `hello` every second. This is done using the `bar` method, which is added to the scheduler as a job.

**Problem:** However when the line `self.db.animals.insert_one({'name': 'lion'})` is added to the `bar` method, running the script gives an error

```
No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"
```

and the script stalls. Any idea what happened and how we can solve it?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import pymongo

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, db, interval=1):
        self.interval = interval
        self.db = db
        self.sched = BlockingScheduler()
        self.sched.add_job(self.bar, 'interval', seconds = interval)

    def start(self):
        self.sched.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.sched.shutdown()

    def bar(self):
        print 'hello'
        self.db.animals.insert_one({'name': 'lion'})


client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.earth
foo = Foo(db, 0.2)
foo.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, but a warning. Python's logging system is trying to tell you that it has no outlet for logging output because you haven't configured it. Try using `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`.